# Java loop for game

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with my code. For some reason, each time I run the code the " if (guess <1 || guess >10 )
            System.out.println ("Your guess needs to be between 1 and 10");" statement is counted as a guessing attempt. The goal is to not have the attempt count if the player is guessing out of the 1-10 range. I've tried a break;, but I can't get it right? Does anyone know how to break the loop and return to the guessing, if a user is out of range(without it counting as an attempt)?

Thank you

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessTheNumber {
private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();
private int numberOfGuesses;

public void play() {
    numberOfGuesses = 0;
    int magicNumber = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt(10);

    int guess = askForGuess();



    while(guess != magicNumber){
    // Some kind of loop, maybe while
    numberOfGuesses++;
    // is theGuess equal to magicNumber or is it
    guess = input.nextInt();
    // too high or is it too low




    if (guess == magicNumber)
    System.out.println("Yes, the number is " + magicNumber);

  else if (guess > magicNumber)
    System.out.println("Your guess is too high");

  else if (guess < magicNumber)
    System.out.println("Your guess is too low");

          System.out.println  ("Number of times guessed: "
    + numberOfGuesses );
    // Display "correct in numberOfGuesses"



    }

  }


}

private int askForGuess( ) {

    int guess = 0;


     // prompt for a guess
    System.out.println("Enter a number:");

    if (guess <1 || guess >10 )
        System.out.println ("Your guess needs to be between 1 and 10");

  return guess;



      }

   }
```

Comment: The question isn't clear - please see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take input in the method "askForGuess()" also the increment will be done there too some thing like following

```
public class GuessTheNumber 
{
private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();
private int numberOfGuesses;

public void play() {
    numberOfGuesses = 0;
    int magicNumber = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt(10);

    int guess = 0;

    while(guess != magicNumber){
    // Some kind of loop, maybe while
    guess = askForGuess();
    // is theGuess equal to magicNumber or is it

    if (guess == magicNumber)
    System.out.println("Yes, the number is " + magicNumber);

  else if (guess > magicNumber)
    System.out.println("Your guess is too high");

  else if (guess < magicNumber)
    System.out.println("Your guess is too low");

          System.out.println  ("Number of times guessed: " + numberOfGuesses );
    }

  }

private int askForGuess( ) 
{
    int guess = 0;
     // prompt for a guess
    System.out.println("Enter a number:");

    guess = input.nextInt();

    if (guess <1 || guess >10 )
        System.out.println ("Your guess needs to be between 1 and 10");
    else
        numberOfGuesses++;

  return guess;
}

}
```